# Including variables inside curly braces in a Zend config ini file on Linux

Tags: php, zend-framework, parsing, config, ini

I am trying to include a variable in a .ini file setting by surrounding it with curly braces, and Zend is complaining that it cannot parse it properly on Linux. It works properly on Windows, though:

```
welcome_message = Welcome, {0}.
```

This is the error that is being thrown on Linux:

```
:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Error parsing /var/www/html/portal/application/configs/language/messages.ini on line 10
' in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php:181
Stack trace:
0 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(201): Zend_Config_Ini-&gt;_parseIniFile('/var/www/html/p...')
1 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(125): Zend_Config_Ini-&gt;_loadIniFile('/var/www/html/p...')
2 /var/www/html/portal/library/Ingrain/Language/Base.php(49): Zend_Config_Ini-&gt;__construct('/var/www/html/p...', NULL)
3 /var/www/html/portal/library/Ingrain/Language/Base.php(23): Ingrain_Language_Base-&gt;setConfig('messages.ini', NULL, NULL)
4 /var/www/html/portal/library/Ingrain/Language/Messages.php(7): Ingrain_Language_Base-&gt;__construct('messages.ini', NULL, NULL, NULL)
5 /var/www/html/portal/library/Ingrain/Helper/Language.php(38): Ingrain_Language_Messages-&gt;__construct()
6 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Contr in
```

We are able to get the error to go away on Linux if we surround the braces with quotes, but that seems like a strange solution:

```
welcome_message = Welcome, "{"0"}".
```

Is there a better way to solve this issue for all platforms? Thanks for your help,

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about having the whole message between quotes ?

A bit like this :

```
welcome_message = "Welcome, {0}."
```

Quoting the documentation of [`parse_ini_file`][1] *(which `Zend_Config_Ini` might use)* :

> Note: If a value in the ini file
> contains any non-alphanumeric
> characters it needs to be enclosed in
> double-quotes (`"`).

And, also *(emphasis mine)* :

> Note:  There are reserved words which
> must not be used as keys for ini
> files. 
> These include: `null`, `yes`, `no`,
> `true`, `false`, `on`, `off`, `none`. 
> Values
> `null`, `no` and `false` results in `""`, yes
> and true results in `"1"`. 
> **Characters
> `{}|&~![()^"`** must not be used
> anywhere in the key and **have a
> special meaning in the value**.

Comment: Zend Config Ini does indeed use parse_ini_file. I recommend PHP configs for performance and flexibility but if using ini, this will work.

Comment: Surrounding the whole message in quotes seems to work great! Thank you so much for your help. I am curious about the performance issue with ini files, David.

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; about performances, you can cache the config object, if needed.

Comment: @David - If the value isn't quoted, it gets treated as a constant, which is why you can do this: `bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"`